# code exited -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I am trying to write a simple program. Vs 2019, Windows 10 64bits

Debug->x64

Followed [Configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms][1]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "res/resource.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <core_api/lsproject.h>
#include <core_api/lslocalworkspace.h>
#include <plugin_api/lsscenecontext.h>
using namespace SCENE_API;
using namespace std;
#include <Commdlg.h>


int main()
{       

    LSString filePath;    

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Where [LSString][2] can be found here.

I am getting an error:

```
The program '[11460] FAPPS.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

-------------------EDITED--------------------------------------------------

After running the executable in debug mode in visual studio, I am getting

```
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\VS_Programm\FARO_SCENE\myfirstapp1\x64\Debug\myfirstapp1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\VS_Programm\FARO_SCENE\myfirstapp1\x64\Debug\Core_API.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\umpdc.dll'. 
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'myfirstapp1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x64c0 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x6604 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x644 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[25976] myfirstapp1.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

Comment: dependencywalker does not support Windows 10. The issue is probably with your proprietary DLLs (I suggest to get in touch with your vendor, faro.com).

Comment: ***How to install "ucrtbased.dll"?*** If you are on windows 10 this is already installed. It is part of the OS.

Comment: I know, I read other answers regarding it, updated window, newly started but still error is there.

Comment: Unloaded is not an error. it probably happened because of the real error which likely happened before this line in the output.

Comment: Nothing there to help. You may want to try he following  dependency walker replacement: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Before going to complex try repairing your visual studio installation from the vs installer. It worked form. Then try to install the latest SDKs for your platform (x64 for example, be careful) from the official Microsoft website. I apologize for my terrible english. Greetings from Italy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run your executable in debug mode in visual studio. It prints the library its trying to load .

[image]