# Unable to run executable that uses GLEW on VSCode terminals

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, mingw-w64, glew

I'm trying to compile and run a tutorial main.cpp that uses OpenGL, GLEW, GLFW, and GLM. I generally use a makefile to clean, compile and run my program. While cleaning and building works fine, when it runs the executable it outputs this error: `make: *** [Makefile:99: run] Error -1073741515`

I tried using the integrated and external terminals in VSCode to run the executable, but it still wouldn't open. However, when I tried running it on a normal command prompt/PowerShell, it cleans, compiles, and runs perfectly well. In addition, when I comment out (`ctrl + /`) every line that uses GLEW and try to compile and run, it works fine.

Although it's a minor issue, I wanted to continue using VSCode's integrated terminal by resolving this issue.

main.cpp:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace glm;

int main() {
    
    // Initialise GLFW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4); // We want OpenGL 4.6
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); // We don't want the old OpenGL 

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window; // (In the accompanying source code, this variable is global for simplicity)
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    do{
        // Clear the screen. It's not mentioned before Tutorial 02, but it can cause flickering, so it's there nonetheless.
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
        glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );
}
```

makefile:

```
#
# 'make'        build executable file 'main'
# 'make clean'  removes all .o and executable files
#

# define the Cpp compiler to use
CXX = g++

# define any compile-time flags
CXXFLAGS    := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g

# define library paths in addition to /usr/lib
#   if I wanted to include libraries not in /usr/lib I'd specify
#   their path using -Lpath, something like:
LFLAGS += -LC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin
LFLAGS += -LC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib

# define output directory
OUTPUT  := output

# define source directory
SRC     := src

# define include directory
INCLUDE := include

# define lib directory
LIB     := lib

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
MAIN    := main.exe
SOURCEDIRS  := $(SRC)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(INCLUDE)
LIBDIRS     := $(LIB)
FIXPATH = $(subst /,\,$1)
RM          := del /q /f
MD  := mkdir
else
MAIN    := main
SOURCEDIRS  := $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -type d)
LIBDIRS     := $(shell find $(LIB) -type d)
FIXPATH = $1
RM = rm -f
MD  := mkdir -p
endif

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
INCLUDES    := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDEDIRS:%/=%))
INCLUDES    += -IC:/Users/kimda/Desktop/Projects/C++/Libraries/glm
INCLUDES    += -IC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include

# define the C libs
LIBS        := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIBDIRS:%/=%))
LIBS        += -lglew32
LIBS        += -lopengl32
LIBS        += -lglfw3
LIBS        += -lgdi32
LIBS        += -lglu32

# define the C source files
SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.cpp, $(SOURCEDIRS)))

# define the C object files 
OBJECTS     := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

#
# The following part of the makefile is generic; it can be used to 
# build any executable just by changing the definitions above and by
# deleting dependencies appended to the file from 'make depend'
#

OUTPUTMAIN  := $(call FIXPATH,$(OUTPUT)/$(MAIN))

all: $(OUTPUT) $(MAIN)
    @echo Building complete!
    

$(OUTPUT):
    @$(MD) $(OUTPUT)

$(MAIN): $(OBJECTS) 
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(OUTPUTMAIN) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# this is a suffix replacement rule for building .o's from .c's
# it uses automatic variables $<: the name of the prerequisite of
# the rule(a .c file) and $@: the name of the target of the rule (a .o file) 
# (see the gnu make manual section about automatic variables)
.cpp.o:
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) $(OUTPUTMAIN)
    @$(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(OBJECTS))
    @echo Cleanup complete!

run: clean all
    @./$(OUTPUTMAIN)
    @echo Executing complete!
```

Clean, Compile, Run on VSCode Terminals:

```
Cleanup complete!
Building complete!
make: *** [Makefile:99: run] Error -1073741515
```

Clean, Compile, Run on Command Prompt/Powershell:

```
Cleanup complete!
Building complete!
Executing complete!
```

Comment: You are gonna have to provide more than that. Ideally a [mcve], stressing the **minimal** part.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do that. Will this suffice?

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the makefile, `make: *** [Makefile:99: run] Error -1073741515` just means that your program returned that value which stops the makefile. I guess that if you run program from the same prompt you run `make`, it will return the same code. In that case startup your favourite debugger and see why is it returning it. I do not see anything wrong in particular with your code.

Comment: Not sure if this is what was supposed to happen, but after I ran a debugger, everything works fine now. In the debug console a warning does pop up however: `Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Your `main` function lacks a final `return` statement, so the value you see here is some arbitrary data on your stack (which of course can change if you change the code).

Comment: Exit code `Error -1073741515` is `0xC0000135` related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411677/code-exited-1073741515-0xc0000135-a-dependent-dll-was-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411677/code-exited-1073741515-0xc0000135-a-dependent-dll-was-not-found) also you can lookup the code here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55)